# 7 segment display with given sequence

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, 7segmentdisplay

[image]I need to design the 7 segment display which show the numbers of 1-7-2-9-0-2-0-9 with the flip-flops. But I can't make the karnough map because of the repeated numbers of 2-9-0. Can you help me with this ?

Comment: I must admit I don't understand the connection between K map and the fact that 290 appear multiple times? Why is that a problem?

Comment: Draw a state table first. Then derive your k map

Comment: also: divide your problem into a problem for each *segment*, instead of trying to do it for all 7 segments at once.

Comment: -what do you mean divide for each segment ? Can you explain it?

Comment: And also when I draw a state table and k-map, it overwrites itself when I use 2-0-9 so thats why outputs come wrong. That's why I couldn't make it.

Comment: what do your states look like? I don't see how this problem arises.

Comment: I add the state table I did. As you can see there is two different output for the same input when chaneging 2-0 and 2-9. It causes a problem on k-map

Comment: the states on the top of your table make sense (for the columns). But you use a different set of states on the left (for the rows). That makes no sense!

Comment: So what do you suggest, how should I do this? this is really important.

Comment: Your sates are Q_0=000, Q_1=001 to Q_7=111, *not* 0,1,2,7,9; you confuse "state number" with "7 segment output". Hence, my recommendation above. Pick up **one** of your segments, for example, the horizontal top bar in your 7-segment display. Then, write down what the output is *for that single segment* in the 8 states.

Answer (score 2):

You can have two different machine states produce the same output, there's no need to use the same state to represent the repeated digits.

call your machine states s1 s2 s3 s4 etc. they have a simple progression where each changes to the next state on a clock signal. you need 8 one for each place in your output (or more depending on what happens after the last digit.)

Now draw a Karnaugh map for each segment of the 7 segment vs the flip-flops or counters you used to make the states.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying that your problem is that the same present state can go to different next states depending on whereabouts in the sequence you are. For example a present state of 2 can go to a next state of 9 or 0 and a present state of 0 can go to a next state of 9 or 2.

A way forward for you would be to design a 3 bit synchronous up counter with JK flipflops (or use a standard chip) which counts upwards from 0 to 7 (you have 8 states). Then decode off the counter outputs so that when the counter is at 0, 1 is displayed. A count of 1 displays 7. A count of 2 displays 2 etc etc.

You would then solve the K-maps with Q1, Q2 and Q3 counter outputs on the K-map axis. A K-map would be required to minimize the logic for each display segment, so 7 K-maps in all for the display.

Not forgetting that, if you decide to design your own up counter, you'd need another set of K-maps to design it. If you use JK flipflops then you'd need another 6 K-maps in addition to the 7 required to minimise the display driver logic.

This design is instead of trying to design a state machine which steps through your 8 states.

Answer (score 0):

You can try similar this way, driving directly from AND gates for common cathode display (for com. anode  via transistor). You need to add another 6 AND gates (8 together). For repeating numbers just put OR after repeating ANDs and use diode combination only once.

[image]

[image]